# How to test controller with AuthenticationManagerBuilder and SecurityContextHolder?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, authentication, spring-security

I have such controller. I want to test that it returns JWT token in header.

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody AuthDto authDto) {

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken
            = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authDto.getUsername(),
                    authDto.getPassword()
    );

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManagerBuilder.getObject().authenticate(authenticationToken);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    String jwt = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt);

    return new ResponseEntity<>("", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I tried such test. I was expecting that authenticationManagerBuilder would be injected into authController as a mock and no its methods would be invoked. Actually I wanted to skip lines in controller with authenticationManagerBuilder and SecurityContextHolder because I don't want to test them.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AuthControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;

    @InjectMocks
    private AuthController authController;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnUserDtoAndBearerToken() {
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        AuthDto authDto = AuthDto.builder().username(username).password(password).build();

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken
                = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                authDto.getUsername(),
                authDto.getPassword()
        );

        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        Mockito.when(authenticationManagerBuilder.getObject())
                        .thenReturn(new ProviderManager());

        Mockito.when(authenticationManagerBuilder.getObject().authenticate(authenticationToken))
                        .thenReturn(authentication);

        Mockito.mock(SecurityContextHolder.class);

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = authController.login(authDto);

        Assertions.assertTrue(responseEntity.getHeaders().containsKey("Authorization"));
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, responseEntity.getHeaders().get("Authorization").size());
        Assertions.assertTrue(responseEntity.getHeaders().get("Authorization").get(0).startsWith("Bearer"));
        Assertions.assertNotEquals("Bearer", responseEntity.getHeaders().get("Authorization").get(0));
    }
}
```

It crushed with such exception.

```
Cannot invoke "java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean.get()" because "this.building" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean.get()" because "this.building" is null
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.getObject(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:50)
    at com.corporation.controller.AuthController.login(AuthController.java:36)
    at com.corporation.controller.auth.AuthControllerTest.shouldReturnUserDtoAndBearerToken(AuthControllerTest.java:52)
```